# didSelectAnnotationView not called for ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on universal ios app which runs on iPhone, iPad and iPod-touch. I have

implemented the code for annotation and on selecting this annotation a `callout` would be

raised. It works fine for iPhone but `didSelectAnnotationView` method not called for iPad.

Should i add any additional to work for iPad? Thanks in advance

Comment: please share code..!!

Comment: where is delegate set i am not found set delegate in you pastebin code :( so please set Delegate as i mention in my answer hope its working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code i think you just forget to set Delegate in checking of device if else condition. please check Properly. if `didSelectAnnotationView` called in iphone but not in ipad it means for ipad condition you not set  `mapView.delegate = self;` for ipad Condition.

So please check properly and set its delegate if your code working for iPhone so that probability for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

see if adding this helps. `[annotationView setCanShowCallout:NO]`

Comment: can we see your map setup? are you setting the delegate correctly? (I assume you are since you are getting the view on the iPhone but it is hard to debug without much code.